# Wikipedia client - embedded Ruby and Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, embedded-ruby

I've installed the following Gem into my Gemfile. 
    https://github.com/kenpratt/wikipedia-client

I've included the following code in my home.html.erb file (code for homepage)

```
<% require 'wikipedia' %>
<% page = Wikipedia.find('Getting Things Done') %>
<h1> <% page.title %> </h1>
```

but nothing shows up on my homepage.  What could be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `=` sign to your tag:

```
<h1> <%= page.title %> </h1>
```